# Vigenere cipher in c++ with txt file input/output

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got to make a Vigenere cipher in c++ that inputs plain text/key from txt files, ciphers/deciphers it and outputs the ciphered text into file as well. I am completely green with coding, but i managed to write this:

```
char alphabet[32][32] = { 'A','Ą','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','Ł','M','N','O','Ó','P','Q','R','S','Ś','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Ź','Ż' };



std::vector<std::string> readPlain(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> to_table;
    
    std::ifstream plain (filename);
    if (plain.is_open())
    {   
        while ( getline (plain, line))
        {
            to_table.push_back(line);

        }
        plain.close();
    }
    else std::cout << "cant open file" << std::endl;

    return to_table;
}

std::vector<std::string> readKey(const std::string& key)
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> to_table;

    std::ifstream plain(key);
    if (plain.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(plain, line))
        {
            to_table.push_back(line);

        }
        plain.close();
    }
    else std::cout << "cant open file" << std::endl;

    return to_table;
}
void encipher(std::vector<std::string> plaintext , std::vector<std::string> key) 
{ 


}
```

on the net i found this piece of code and i think i can sew this together to get it working

```
int tableArr[26][26];
void createVigenereTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            int temp;
            if ((i + 65) + j > 90) {
                temp = ((i + 65) + j) - 26;

                //adding ASCII of alphabet letter in table index position
                tableArr[i][j] = temp;
            }
            else {
                temp = (i + 65) + j;

                //adding ASCII of alphabet letter in table index position
                tableArr[i][j] = temp;
            }
        } // for j loop
    } // for i loop

void cipherEncryption(string message, string mappedKey) {
    createVigenereTable();
    string encryptedText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        if (message[i] == 32 && mappedKey[i] == 32) {
            encryptedText += " ";
        }
        else {
            int x = (int)message[i] - 65;
            int y = (int)mappedKey[i] - 65;
            encryptedText += (char)tableArr[x][y];
        }
    }

    cout << "Encrypted Text: " << encryptedText;
}
```

how can i make it work like this, but on vectors? or what do i do to transform vector into ints for it to work?  maybe should i start from scratch using something different? Any help will be greatly apperiecated. Thank you

Comment: When you're thinking of using found code, the first thing to do is work thought the code line by line and map out the behaviour to make sure you understand what it's doing and how. If you can't, it's time to move on. Assuming you do understand, what differences between `string` and `vector` are holding up your adaptation?

Comment: Note: be wary of all of the magic numbers in the code. The writer has made some assumptions that are usually true, ASCII encoded character set, but are a real kick in the teeth when violated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but a couple of hints: 1) To my knowledge, the Vigenere cipher takes in a string as key, but you pass a vector of strings. Why? 2) in the code you downloaded, they explicitely use the ASCII alphabet which has a simple integer <-> character correspondence (the +-65 stuff). You have non ASCII characters, so you will have to use your alphabet instead.

Comment: Beside that, what is more meaningful during a casual read of the code, `65` or `'A'`?

Comment: @Cedric Thank you. It's really hard to wrap my head around this for the school project, but i hope i can make it